# How to detect a working ttyUSB for my usb modem

Tags: usb, openwrt

I working with OpenWRT and need setup USB 3G Modem. When i connect USB modem i see in logs that system create four ttyUSB. Why four?

```
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.220000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.230000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.240000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: generic converter detected
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.280000] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.280000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.290000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.300000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: generic converter detected
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.340000] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.340000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.2: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.350000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.2: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.360000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.2: generic converter detected
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.440000] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.450000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.3: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.450000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.3: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
Tue Jul 29 07:45:23 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.460000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.3: generic converter detected
Tue Jul 29 07:45:24 2014 kern.info kernel: [  580.500000] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB3
```

After this i know that modem is working. Therefore i setup network interface where i must select a working ttyUSB. But how can i know which ttyUSB is work? For each port i run

```
gcom -d /dev/ttyUSB0 info
gcom -d /dev/ttyUSB1 info
etc...
```

For find working port. But this method is not good because slow and hard to parse. I should write a bash script to detect working ttyUSB for my modem and put in network config. How can i do it?

My router have only one USB port. Every USB 3G Modem use different ttyUSB port.

PS. How can i imagine i can send some data to each port and check result. If result good, then use this ttyUSB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't found better way that parse gcom command result.

```
## Search for a working USB port (/dev/ttyUSB)

work=false
for port in /dev/ttyUSB*
do
    [[ -e $port ]] || continue
    gcom -d $port info &> /tmp/testusb
    testUSB=`cat /tmp/testusb | grep "Error\|Can't"`
    if [ -z "$testUSB" ]; then 
        work=$port
        break
    fi
done
rm -rf /tmp/testusb

if [ $work != false ]; then
    echo "$work is working!"
else 
    echo 'Not found a working USB port'
fi
```

Comment: What is `/tmp/testusb`? Can you `cat` it?